# Trying to insert image into my database. All the time saving the same thing plsss help I am lost

Tags: c#, sql-server

While I am trying to insert image into my data base it all the time saves this:

> 0xFFD8FFE145AB4578696600004D4D002A00000008000A011200030000000100000000021300030000000100010000011A0005000000010000018E011B0005000000010000019601280003000000010002000001320002000000140000019E010F000200000064000001B201100002000000640000021687690004000000010000

Even if the image is null.

Please help.

C# Code:

```
if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName!="")
{
    Byte[] image;
    Stream s = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(s);
    image = br.ReadBytes((Int32)s.Length);

    SqlCommand NewUser = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [User] Values (@username,@password,@name,@lastname,@location,@profesion,@email,@gender,@money,@pro,@xp,@lv,@m1,@m2,@m3,@m4,@m5,@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@im,@phone);", c);
    NewUser.Connection = c;

    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtuser.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpass.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtFName.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", txtLName.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", ddlcountry.SelectedItem.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profesion", txtprofession.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", rbgendere.SelectedItem.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@money", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pro", DBNull.Value);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xp", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lv", 1);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m1", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m2", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m3", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m4", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m5", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d4", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d5", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@im", image);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", PhoneNumber.Text);

    Session["CurentUserid"] = txtuser.Text;

    c.Open();
    int row = NewUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
    c.Close();

    if (row > 0)
    {
        LabelError.Text = "success";
    }

    Session["Conect"] = (bool)true;
    Response.Redirect("Finish Had Member.aspx", true);       
}
else
{
    SqlCommand NewUser = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [User] Values (@username,@password,@name,@lastname,@location,@profesion,@email,@gender,@money,@pro,@xp,@lv,@m1,@m2,@m3,@m4,@m5,@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@im,@phone);", c);
    NewUser.Connection = c;

    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtuser.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpass.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtFName.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", txtLName.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", ddlcountry.SelectedItem.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profesion", txtprofession.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", rbgendere.SelectedItem.Text);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@money", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pro", DBNull.Value);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xp", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lv", 1);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m1", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m2", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m3", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m4", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m5", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d4", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d5", 0);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@im", DBNull.Value);
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", PhoneNumber.Text);

    Session["CurentUserid"] = txtuser.Text;

    c.Open();
    NewUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
    c.Close();

    Session["Conect"] = (bool)true;
    Response.Redirect("Finish Had Member.aspx", true);
}
```

Comment: How about a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: you right mate but i dont know were is the problem and i search so hard plss help....

Comment: Step 1 is to [Stop Using `AddWithValue`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). That may or may not be the problem here, but you are playing Russian Roulette with your data.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a working example change accordingly

Html of page

```
<div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Image Name:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtImageName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Upload Image:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileuploadImage" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvImages" CssClass="Gridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            HeaderStyle-BackColor="#7779AF" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="white">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Image Name" DataField="imagename" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "Handler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("ImageID") %>'
                            Height="150px" Width="150px" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

Code behind

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fileuploadImage.HasFile)
        {
            //getting length of uploaded file
            int length = fileuploadImage.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            //create a byte array to store the binary image data
            byte[] imgbyte = new byte[length];
            //store the currently selected file in memeory
            HttpPostedFile img = fileuploadImage.PostedFile;
            //set the binary data
            img.InputStream.Read(imgbyte, 0, length);
            string imagename = txtImageName.Text;
            //use the web.config to store the connection string
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Image (ImageName,Image) VALUES (@imagename,@imagedata)", connection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = imagename;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagedata", SqlDbType.Image).Value = imgbyte;
            int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            if (count == 1)
            {
                BindGridData();
                txtImageName.Text = string.Empty;
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertmessage", "javascript:alert('" + imagename + " image inserted successfully')", true);
            }
        }
    }
    private void BindGridData()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT imagename,ImageID from [Image]", connection);
        SqlDataAdapter daimages = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        daimages.Fill(dt);
        gvImages.DataSource = dt;
        gvImages.DataBind();
        gvImages.Attributes.Add("bordercolor", "black");
    }
```

Right Click on your project add new `Generic Handler` name it -> Handler.ashx

Replace `ProcessRequest` with this

```
string strcon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string imageid = context.Request.QueryString["ImID"];
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strcon);
        connection.Open();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("select Image from Image where ImageID=" + imageid, connection);
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dr[0]);
        connection.Close();
        context.Response.End();
    }
```

In web Config add this under `<configuration> -> <connectionStrings>`

Here DataBase name in my case is `testDB`

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=testDB;trusted_Connection=yes"/>
```

Create Table in SQL using this query

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Image](
    [ImageId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ImageName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Image] [image] NULL
)
```

Hope This will help you

Answer (score 1):

try

```
command.Parameters.Add("@im", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = image;
```

It has to match the SQL column type.
According to the answer from Ansari Image is the correct type.